# Omitting access-control-allow-headers in CORS / preflight response

Tags: cors, http-headers

I’m having trouble finding information explaining what happens if the response to a preflight request or the response to the actual CORS request omits `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. I have noticed that several sites say this header is required when the request includes `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

I would like to allow CORS access to my API with any headers, so I’m wondering if omitting this header will do just that and allow all headers.

My API requires that you send an `Authorization` header containing an OAuth token and typically the client will also send a cookie. There are sites that say that using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` only acts as a wildcard when `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `false`.

This seems to put me in a bind since I want the CORS request to include credentials (the `Authorization` header and a cookie) but I also want to allow all headers. How can I make this work?

A secondary question is why would I want to restrict the request to an allowed set of headers? In my case the API is a `GET` which makes no changes on the server. I want allowed origins to always be able to retrieve this information. Under what circumstances would the headers they include play into that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I’m having trouble finding information explaining what happens if the response to a preflight request or the response to the actual CORS request omits `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. I have noticed that several sites say this header is required when the request includes `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

Those sites are correct: if the preflight request contains an `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header, then the response to that request must, at the very least, contain an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header, or CORS preflight will fail. The actual header value required for CORS preflight to succeed will differ on the basis of which header names were specified in the preflight request.

> I would like to allow CORS access to my API with any headers, so I’m wondering if omitting this header will do just that and allow all headers.

No, omitting the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in the response to the preflight request does not count as a pass.

> My API requires that you send an `Authorization` header containing an OAuth token and typically the client will also send a cookie. There are sites that say that using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` only acts as a wildcard when `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `false`.

Close, but imprecise. Rather, you cannot use the wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` if you use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax

> This seems to put me in a bind since I want the CORS request to include credentials (the `Authorization` header and a cookie) but I also want to allow all headers. How can I make this work?

In that case, you cannot use the wildcard. You only have one way: take all the header names listed in the preflight request's `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header and reflect them in the response's `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.

> A secondary question is why would I want to restrict the request to an allowed set of headers? In my case the API is a `GET` which makes no changes on the server. I want allowed origins to always be able to retrieve this information. Under what circumstances would the headers they include play into that?

I may be missing something, but I don't think this is problematic if the set of allowed origins is finite. However, if you allow arbitrary origins, you probably shouldn't allow arbitrary headers on authenticated endpoints. In particular, allowing the `Authorization` for arbitrary origins opens the door to client-side, distributed brute-force of Bearer tokens (or whatever the `Authorization` normally contains); more about that in https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/251#issuecomment-209265586